# Relative Layout missing from the last version of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

activity_main is a relative layout, but android studio can't recognise it. Also, in the layout menu there's no relative layout, and the I can't move the button freely, it's stuck in that corner, I need to give it margin or to align it. This happened after I updated my android studio to the lastest version. What can I do? I need to work with that layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XSJC.png

Comment: post the error code

Comment: Doesn't recognize it how?

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: Do refactor, may it help you

Comment: Your base layout is `ConstrainLayout`. You can change that to `RelativeLayout` from xml. Please add your xml code for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of **`legacy option`** RelativeLayout is present. Please refer the following screenshot:

[image: drag and drop]

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the view:

- -Right click on component
- -Select convert view
- -Find and click RelativeLayout
- -Apply

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).